# What could be wrong in my C++ code for finding nth term in AP?

Tags: c++, math

```
   class Solution {
 public:
   int nthTermOfAP(int A1, int A2, int N) {
  int d=A2-A1;
  int current=A1;
  int arr[10];
  
  for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
     arr[i]=current;
     current+d;
  }
  cout<<arr[N-1];
}
};
// { Driver Code Starts.
int main() {
   int t;
   cin >> t;
   while (t--) {
       int A1, A2, N;
       cin >> A1 >> A2 >> N;
       Solution ob;
       cout << ob.nthTermOfAP(A1, A2, N) << "\n";
   }
}
 // } Driver Code Ends
```

i am getting output as 26295968. Please explain why i am getting such a large number? do i have to intialize any number to 0?

Comment: is N > 10 by any chance? Did you stay inside the bounds of arr[10]? You might want to use std::vector<int> v(N) instead of int arr[10];

Answer (score 1):

Your nthTermOfAP function doesn't return any value. So when you try to cout the function that doesn't return any value, its gonna give you an output like 26295968.

So you can either do two things:

1. Add a return value in your nthTermOfAP function.
2. Simply remove the `cout` from `cout << ob.nthTermOfAP(A1, A2, N) << "\n";` in your `int main()`. And make the function datatype into `void` instead of `int`. With `void` you are not expected to give a return value.

Comment: `void` for what function??

Comment: For nthTermOfAP

Answer (score 0):

The return type of your function should be void instead of int. Then you can remove the cout command.
Instead of
current+d;
You should use
current = current+d;

```
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
       arr[i]=current;
       current = current+d;
    }
    cout<<arr[N-1];
```

Also you can used the equation nth term of an Ap= a+(n-1)*d